# How show text in centre of each rectangle using onDraw

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm trying to create a text view (black colour) containing numbers 1 to 7 (each number on top and in the centre of each grey rectangle - just like the image I've drawn below) but I'm not sure what properties I need to add in order to achieve this. I believe the code needs to go in the loop section but I don't what code. What can be done so that a number appears centralised in each grey rectangle?

**desired outcome**

[image]

**current outcome**

[image]

```
public class RectangleTextView extends View {
    private final Paint mBackPaint = new Paint();
    private final Paint mRedPaint = new Paint();
    private int mSideRectWidth = 10;

    public RectangleTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mBackPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRedPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (getWidth() == 0)
            return;

        //draw grey boxes
        setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"));
        int boxWidth = getWidth() / 7;

        //draw black lines and/or draw text in centre of each rectangle
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            canvas.drawLine(mSideRectWidth + boxWidth * i, 0, mSideRectWidth + boxWidth * i, getHeight(), mBackPaint);
        canvas.drawText(?);
        }

        //draw text in centre of each rectangle
        ?

        //draw left end rectangle
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, mSideRectWidth, getHeight(), mRedPaint);

        //draw right end rectangle
        canvas.drawRect(getWidth() - mSideRectWidth, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), mRedPaint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `canvas.drawText()`. You can do it in the same loop that you draw the black lines.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    canvas.drawLine(mSideRectWidth + boxWidth * i, 0, mSideRectWidth + boxWidth * i, getHeight(), mBackPaint);
    float x = ...
    float y = ...
    canvas.drawText(Integer.toString(i + 1), x, y, mBlackPaint);
}
```

You will have to figure out the x and y value for the placement of the text. If you use `paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER)`, then that simplifies the x value calculation, it's just halfway between the black lines.

Comment: For the x and y positions, would it be something like getWidgh or getHeight divided by 2?

Comment: You need to calculate them for each piece of text. If you set the text align of the paint as I describe, then `x` should be half the distance between black lines. `y` is a bit harder to answer, but you can start with `getHeight() / 2` and make adjustments from there. Note that you can get the font metrics from the paint object in case any of that information is useful in calculating the `y` value.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Paint.getTextBounds() method to get the bounding area of the text, then the exact center vertically and horizontally can be extracted from the resulting Rect object:

```
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize( textSize );

    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    if( text != null )
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
    else
        bounds.set(0,0,0,0);

    location.x -= bounds.exactCenterX();
    location.y -= bounds.exactCenterY();
```